Can I use template string types to automatically infer types for globalThis keys in TypeScript?
In my Three.js debugging workflow, I often attach objects to globalThis for convenience. However, manually declaring types for each property is becoming tedious as the globalThis object grows larger.
I want to know if TypeScript can automatically infer types for keys that end with a specific string, such as Material.
For example, I would like all properties on globalThis that end with Material (i.e., keys matching the template string type ${string}Material) to be treated as THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial.
declare global {
    var camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera
    var scene: THREE.Scene
    var renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer
    var setCameraToLeft: () => void
    var setCameraToRight: () => void
    var bigBoxMaterial: THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial
    var middleBoxMaterial: THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial
    var smallBoxMaterial: THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial
    ...Material: THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial
}

Perhaps it is a definition similar to this...
declare global {
    var camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera
    var scene: THREE.Scene
    var renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer
    var setCameraToLeft: () => void
    var setCameraToRight: () => void
    [key: string]: key extends `${string}Material` ? THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial : unknown
}


You can't create an index-signature-named variable, nor can you merge into typeof globalThis. There aren't a lot of handles for manipulating the global type. The closest I can get is to add an index signature to Window and then you access your variables only as window properties, as shown in this playground link. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz I believe this example is exactly what I was looking for. I have to replace all instances of globalThis with window in my web code, which isn't as modern. Thank you for your help!

Looks like you want to merge an index signature into typeof globalThis. Unfortunately that's not possible; there's a feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#57353 for that, but it doesn't have much engagement, so I doubt we'll see this soon.
The closest I can imagine getting is to merge an index signature into an interface that corresponds to the global object, such as the Window interface in the DOM:
declare global {
    interface Window {
        [k: `${string}Material`]: THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial
    }
}

That's using a template string pattern index signature to say that every key ending in Material will have a property of type THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial (which isn't likely to be true, right? Maybe you want | undefined in there or maybe you want to use --noUncheckedIndexedAccess)
Then you can index into window (but not into globalThis or use a global variable) to access things:
window.randomMaterial.alphaHash; // okay

You could also possibly redeclare globalThis like
declare let globalThis: Window

and then globalThis.randomMaterial.alphaHash works, but this is getting even more fragile.
So you can get somewhat closer to your goal than just giving up, but I don't know that it's worth the effort. In some sense it's no better than just using a type assertion on a variable that references globalThis, and not trying to actually mess with merging at all:
const myGlobal = globalThis as typeof globalThis & {
    [k: `${string}Material`]: THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial
};
myGlobal.randomMaterial.alphaHash; // okay

Playground link to code
